# Pass env variable as variable which should be resolved in context of container

Tags: docker, environment-variables

Sorry for the wording of the question. But I don't know what to call it.

What i want:

```
➜  hub git:(develop) ✗ docker run -e A=b -it alpine echo $A
b
```

What i got and what i tried:

```
➜  hub git:(develop) ✗ docker run -e A=b -it alpine echo "$A"

➜  hub git:(develop) ✗ docker run -e A=b -it alpine echo $A  

➜  hub git:(develop) ✗ docker run -e A=b -it alpine echo '$A'
$A
➜  hub git:(develop) ✗ docker run -e A=b -it alpine echo \$A 
$A
➜  hub git:(develop) ✗ docker run -e A=b -it alpine echo \\$A
\
```

Yes i know that i can do it like

```
➜  hub git:(develop) ✗ docker run -e A=b -it alpine sh       
/ # echo $A
b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable substitution is provided by shell, but you have no shell while echo'ing. Just use shell :)

`docker run -e A=b -it alpine sh -c "echo \$A"`